# How can I learn about economics?

Tags: self-study

I'm a civil engineering student and I'm interested in economics and I would like to learn everything about it. I would like to learn everything from banks to the stock markets and everything there is to learn about. I always read articles about stocks and the market but I feel really ignorant. Can you recommend me some introductory books or some learning ressources? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Banks and the stock market" are _not_ "everything" about economics, far from it. But even if "Banks and the stock market" are truly what you are really interested in (in which case, it would perhaps be a good idea to delete from your post the "everything" things),  you have to move at least one more step: do you want to learn how Banks, and the stock market function in terms of rules and regulations and the like, or what are the economics/financial economics way of studying them? Etc Clarifications like these would help us help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend Tim Harford's "The Undercover Economist" for an easy way to get some exposure to how economists think, without having to go through all of the dry academic mathematics etc.

To get a sense of the shape of the economics discipline, you might also like to look at "Economics: A Very Short Introduction" by Partha Dasgupta.

Lastly, if you really want to get into the discipline and you want a slightly more formalised/academic treatment then any good introductory textbook should do. N. Gregory Mankiw's "Economics" is a popular choice.

---

The above describes how you might go about learning about economics. But **from your question, it seems more like you are more interested in learning about finance**, which is the discipline that encompasses the study financial markets, etc. I learnt finance from a book called "Introduction to Finance" by Lawrence J. Gitman and Jeff Madura, but there doesn't seem to be a recent edition so perhaps someone else can recommend a more recent introduction to the subject.